Как в javascript передать значение из одного класса в другой в ООП?
Чтобы лучше понять реализацию ООП, я стараюсь разобраться на практическом примере.
Пытаюсь передать значение из класса GamePlay в класс View.
В draw_cell(cellIdx) console.log выводит newVal = undefined.
Хотелось бы, чтобы newVal присвоилось значение переменной let value = 77;
Код:
const GamePlay = (function create_game_play() {     
    let game = create_game();
    
    function create_game() {
       
        let value = 77;
        console.log('value = ' + value);
        let game = {
           
        }
        return game
    }

    function start_game() {
        View.render_start_game(game);
    }

    var game_play = {        
        game: game,
        start_game() { start_game() },
    }

    return game_play
})();

const View = (function create_view() {
   let newVal = null;
   let cellIdx = 0;
   console.log('newVal = ' + newVal);
   
    function draw_cell(cellIdx) {        
        newVal = cellIdx.value;
        console.log('newVal = ' + newVal);
    }
    
     function render_start_game(game) {
        draw_cell(cellIdx);
    }

    return {
        render_start_game: render_start_game,        
    }
})();

GamePlay.start_game()


А что ты передаешь в эту функцию? Ничего, вот там и есть ничего.

Ну формально говоря, у вас тут не совсем классы, как таковые. Вот классы. Обратите внимание, что вы передаете в функцию  render_start_game и что потом в функцию draw_cell - должно навести на мысли

Так же, множественное перекрытие имен переменных - очень плохая история.

Я смог передать значение из функции GamePlay в функцию View.
console.log выводит newVal = 333.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My_QUESTION</title>
   
</head>

<body>
    <h1>My_QUESTION.</h1>
    
    <script>
    
    const GamePlay = (function create_game_play() {
    let VAL_01 = 77;
    
    let game = create_game();
    
    function create_game() {
       
        VAL_01 = 333;
        console.log('VAL_01 = ' + VAL_01);
        let game = {
           
        }
        return game
    }

    function start_game() {
        View.render_start_game(game);
    }

    var game_play = {        
        game: game,
        start_game() { start_game() },
        get VAL_01() { return VAL_01 },
    }

    return game_play
    })();

    const View = (function create_view() {
       let newVal = null;
       let cellIdx = 0;
       console.log('newVal = ' + newVal);   
       newVal = GamePlay.VAL_01;
       console.log('newVal = ' + newVal);
       
        function draw_cell(cellIdx) {        
            console.log('function draw_cell --- newVal = ' + newVal);
        }
        
         function render_start_game(game) {
            draw_cell(cellIdx);
        }

        return {
            render_start_game: render_start_game,        
        }
    })();

    GamePlay.start_game()   
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>

